# Pausing UIGestureRecognizer for parent view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have added a pop up to my app and it lays over the main parent view controller. But when I swipe on the pop up the main view controller is recognizing the swipes. How can I prioritize the child view controller for actions or stop the gesture recognizer on the main view controller while the pop up is open?

Here's the code where I add the child view:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedItem = self.menuItems[indexPath.row]
    let ratingVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "rating") as! RatingView
    ratingVC.mainView = self
    ratingVC.foodName = selectedItem
    self.addChildViewController(ratingVC)
    ratingVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(ratingVC.view)
    ratingVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

Comment: try setting your pop up view property `.isExclusiveTouch == true`  https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622453-isexclusivetouch

Comment: @LeoDabus I just tried that and some actions still went through to the main view Controller

Comment: Please show the code for how you present the "child" view. It's possible something else is going on here, because the default behavior would usually be for views "in front" to have first say about touches unless their parent has explicitly decided against this. I would not recommend messing with isExclusiveTouch, as greedy views seem to be your problem, not your solution.

Comment: @ChrisTrahey I added the code where I add the child view

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for adding the code! It looks like we should change how we are presenting the View Controller. First, I'll explain the simple reason this code doesn't work: When this method returns, the `ratingVC` variable is cleared, and since it is the only reference to your View Controller, that View Controller is cleared from memory. So your touches cannot be sent to it :-)

There are a couple better ways to present a view controller. Your code is doing what is called "View Controller Containment", and it may be overkill unless you know why you are doing it that way.

The first thing you could do is set the presented view controller as a strong property on this table view controller, and then use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` to present it. This is simple, and Apple's libraries handle putting it's view on screen.

The recommended way these days, though, to present a View Controller's scene after a table view cell is tapped goes like this:

1. Use Storyboards to setup both the table view (with prototype cells) and the destination scene.
2. Ctrl-Drag from the cell prototype to the destination scene.
3. In your table view controller's code, use [prepareForSegue:sender:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepareforsegue) to give the destination View Controller it's required state.

As a side note, `ratingVC.mainView = self` in your code may imply another anti-pattern. The easy advice is: Make darn sure that mainView is marked as weak. The better advice is to use a loose-coupling design pattern like delegation, target/action, or callbacks.

Comment: The reason I am placing the view as it is is because I want the main view controller visible in the background. Is that possible with these other methods? also I did make sure mainView is a weak variable I am just using that to pass data back from ratingVC to the main view controller.

Comment: It is sometimes possible with the other presentation methods I mentioned. You can/should specify the presentation styles for your various size classes. Check out this WWDC talk: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/222/

Comment: At any rate, if you keep your presentation style, you'll need to keep a strong reference to your presented view controller ratingVC from your source table VC